# Local variable loses its value: selection sort algorithm

Tags: c, variables, scope, selection-sort

I previously tested the same variable called "swaps" for bubble sort algorithm and it worked perfectly. Now, with selection sorting,  variable loses its value even after incrementing it.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
int list[] = {10, 5, 6, 3, 4, 11, 9, 7, 2};
int min = list[0], pos = 0, temp_max = 0;

// Loop until no swap is needed
for (int j = 0, n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int); j < n; j++)
{
    int swaps = 0, 

    // Iterate through array to find min value
    for (int i = j, y = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int); i < y; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] < min)
        {
            min = list[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }

    // Insert min value in left most position and add 1 to swaps, meaning array is not yet sorted
    if (pos > j)
    {
        temp_max = list[j];
        list[j] = min;
        list[pos] = temp_max;
        swaps++;
    }

    // The error might occur here: "swaps" keeping value 0 after previous if statement ends
    printf ("swaps = %d\n", swaps);

    // If no swaps ocurred, array is sorted
    if (swaps == 0)
    {       
        // Print sorted array and return  
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `n` in both loops since `y` always has the same value as `n`.  This doesn't affect your problem, though.

Comment: 1) `int swaps = 0,` can't compile. Maybe you want `int swaps = 0;` i.e. `;` instead of `,` 2) After fixing the first problem, I don't see any problems with `swaps` - see http://ideone.com/Z40FXl - it increments just fine. Sure you posted the correct code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding to the other answers, which will fix the problem specifically with your code, you can also approach the selection sort algorithm like this.

### Steps to writing this algorithm for an array:

**1.** Write a helper function to find the index of the biggest element in the array:

```
size_t index_of_largest(int list[], size_t n) {
    size_t i, biggest;

    biggest = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (list[i] > list[biggest]) {
            biggest = i;
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

**2.** Iterate over `i=n` to `i=1`, and find the biggest value between `list[0]` and `list[i-1]`. After this element is found, swap it into the last position. The function could look like this:

```
void sort_list(int list[], size_t n) {
    size_t i, biggest;

    for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        biggest = index_of_largest(list, i);
        int_swap(&list[biggest], &list[i-1]); /* swapping function */
    }
}
```

**3.** Considering these ideas, you can write a simple version of the algorithm like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_list(int list[], size_t n);
size_t index_of_largest(int list[], size_t n);
void print_array(int list[], size_t n);
void int_swap(int *x, int *y);

int main(void) {
    int list[] = {10, 5, 6, 3, 4, 11, 9, 7, 2};
    size_t n = sizeof list / sizeof *list;

    printf("Before: ");
    print_array(list, n);

    sort_list(list, n);

    printf("After: ");
    print_array(list, n);

    return 0;
}

void sort_list(int list[], size_t n) {
    size_t i, biggest;

    for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        biggest = index_of_largest(list, i);
        int_swap(&list[biggest], &list[i-1]);
    }
}

size_t index_of_largest(int list[], size_t n) {
    size_t i, biggest;

    biggest = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (list[i] > list[biggest]) {
            biggest = i;
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}

void print_array(int list[], size_t n) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void int_swap(int *x, int *y) {
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: 10 5 6 3 4 11 9 7 2
After: 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname progname.c
```

Comment: It's nice that you know how to write a selection sort. Don't you think the OP deserves a chance to figure it out on his own as well? The OP's question here is specifically about why the `swaps` variable loses its value, and this answer doesn't address that question at all.

Comment: Caleb, It is a learning experience being is this community, where I learn so much. I will post below my perceptions so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Caleb, I don't understand why you think showing the OP another way to do this algorithm is unacceptable. The OP will learn a lot from seeing different approaches, far more than just pointing out his mistake in the code, as 3 other answers have done already. I don't know how you learned programming, but I sure know that is helpful to anyone learning algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration `int swaps = 0` outside the `for` loop.

---

In other words, change this:

```
for (int j = 0, n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int); j < n; j++)
{
    int swaps = 0;
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
int swaps = 0;
for (int j = 0, n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int); j < n; j++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How come? What if it becomes sorted after 1 iteration?

Comment: @coderredoc: How come what? If it becomes sorted after 1 iteration then everything is good. OP declares this variable inside the scope of the `for` loop, so it obviously retains its value only during this scope (i.e., initialized to 0 at the beginning of every iteration).

Comment: No what I meant is ..in first ioteration we needed to make a swap so swaps changes ..now again in second iteration we see that it is sorted but as it is already set to 1 it won't come out....which is why swaps was used.

Comment: @coderredoc: I have referred only to the OP's complaint about a local variable "losing" its value (also indicated in the code as `The error might occur here: "swaps" keeping value 0 after previous if statement ends`). There could be other problems of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I made some progress with your help. But I pretty sure it has to do with variable scope. The funny thing is, it worked on previous bubble sorting algorithm. Being newbe is a mess =)

Comment: Compiling with *warnings* enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) will help you identify problems. Read the warnings and errors (they are really quite good) and that will help narrow down your issue for you. No magic, just takes doing it enough that it sinks in....

Comment: @MarcelloScattolini: It **DOES** have to do with variable scope. The scope of the `swaps` variable is the `for` loop internals, so at every iteration, this variable is declared and initialized to `0`.

Comment: @barakmanos.: Hey I just don't know one thing...whoever DV'ed I didnt say anything wrong..tell me what is the purpose of that swaps?? Let's see how much wrong i am.

Comment: @coderredoc: I don't understand you question in general. More specifically, what does "DV'ed" mean??? Also, I'm not sure whether or not you're wrong, because I did not read your answer (if that's what you mean). I merely referred to the title of the question, which says "Local variable loses its value" (also described at the beginning of the question). For this problem, the meaning and usage of the variable is not relevant.

Comment: @barakmanos.: the `swaps` is used to so that when it is zero after that second `for` loop then it will get out of it saving the algorithm from extra iterations...that's it. Now when OP asks that it doesn't change its value even after increment then either increment is not working ( which is not possible) or else it is not even incremented....that's why I tried to answer w.r.t the correct approach instead of just making a variables value retain making it out of for loop's scope....that's it...DV= down vote...I just don't know why I am down voted...I don't know whats wrong in my answer...

Comment: @coderredoc: I haven't read your answer yet, so I'm not quite sure. I'm pretty sure that OP has meant to increment this variable to a value larger than 1 (otherwise, he/she could have just as well used `=1` instead of `++`, right?).

Comment: @coderredoc: Nothing much that you can do about the DV, since they left no comment (which is irritating regardless of whether or not there is something wrong with your answer). Since there's nothing much to do about it, I wouldn't spend my worries on it either. You could delete the answer if you wish to get rid of the DV. In fact, I'm considering deleting my own answer **even** with an UV, because the code in the question is pretty messed up as it is, **even** after fixing the 'local variable' problem which I have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank you all very much. I have solved the problem with your help. Turns out the error had to do with the variable scope (where it was declared). Follow below the working code.

```
int main (void)
{

//Declare list to be sorted and other variables
int list[] = {9, 5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6};
int minValPos = 0, maxTempVal = list[0];

for (int j = 0, siz = sizeof (list) / sizeof (int); j < siz; j++)
{
    int swaps = 0, minVal = list[j];

    // Look for min value after each j iteration
    for (int i = j; i < siz; i++)
    {

        // Find minimum value (minVal) and store its position (minValPos)
        if (list[i] < minVal)
        {
            minVal = list[i];
            minValPos = i;
        }

    }

    // Once with MinVal pinpointed, proceed to swap with jth item
    if (minValPos > j)
    {
        maxTempVal = list[j];
        list[j] = minVal;
        list[minValPos] = maxTempVal;
        swaps++;
    }

    // When array did not need any swaps, it means it is sorted
    if (swaps == 0)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < siz; r++)
        {
            printf ("Position [%d] = %d\n", r, list[r]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That means your `if` statement is not becoming true in the meantime.

`min` should be set in each loop of `j`.

`min=list[j]` in `for(j=...){min=list[j]; ... }`

And also `pos=j`

Comment: Coderredoc, I appreciate your help. One observation:  when if statement executes, swaps value changes to 1. But if I printf swaps right after closing bracket, value returns to 0. I guess it has somehing to do with variable scope. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, very well observed.

Comment: @MarcelloScattolini What you are saying is not possible...if  `if` is executed and swaps changes then it can't print `0`

Comment: Reason for my DV?

Comment: what is DV, please? Thanks!